# Is there an easy way to store an array of varying length within a single db row?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, entity-framework

I have a program that stores rows of data where some columns in the row are actually supposed to represent arrays. The problem is that the rows have a predetermined set of columns but the arrays have varying lengths. The example that I have provided is a table of search metadata for musical artists. One of the fields that I have to account for is similar artists. This field represents a varying number of similar artists. What I did was build another entire table called SimilarArtists and mapped out a foreign key to SearchMetadata's Id column. This just seems too complicated to do for a large number of varying length fields. Is there an easier way to do this? Preferably a way that doesn't involve cramming all of the similar artists into the same cell with a unique character separator?

[image]
[image]

P.S. In the provided example, SimilarArtists contains a column called ArtistRankNum which makes it an object instead of an array, therefore necessitating a full table in the db but just imagine if it was only the ArtistName field. Is there an easier way to store this data other than building an entire separate table for it?

Comment: There's no magic here; *either* you need to represent the data via a second table with 0/one/many rows in it per parent row, or you need to hack the data into the single row via something like a delimited string, or JSON/XML, etc

Comment: Or it's possible you're looking at the wrong kind of data storage and some kind of NoSQL solution might be the better approach.

Comment: there is a json-extension fro sqlite: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html

Comment: I agree with you @MarcGravell I think I need a second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a simpler way to do it so I ended up keeping it the way it was. The route I went was adding a second table with a WithMany() foreign key in the `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)` function in ApplicationDbContext.cs like this

```
        builder.Entity<SearchMetadata>()
            .HasKey(s => s.Id);
        builder.Entity<SearchMetadata>()
            .HasOne(s => s.Playlist)
            .WithMany(dp => dp.SearchMetadatas)
            .HasForeignKey("PlaylistId");
        
        builder.Entity<SimilarArtist>()
            .HasOne(sa => sa.SearchMetadata)
            .WithMany(s => s.SimilarArtists)
            .HasForeignKey(sa => sa.SearchMetadataId);
```